# How to bind make Currying with PHP? (like Function.prototype.bind do in javascript)?

Tags: php, function, anonymous

i want https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Currying in PHP:

```
$x = function ($a, $b) {
  echo $a . ' ' . $b;
};

for ($i= 0;$i< 10;$i++) {
  $y = bind($x, $i)// how?
  $y($i);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actual currying is maybe a bit of a stretch for PHP (;-)), nonetheless you can do stuff like this with Closures in PHP 5.3+:

```
function populatedList() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    return function () use ($args) {
        $localArgs = func_get_args();
        return array_merge($args, $localArgs);
    };
}

$sevenList = populatedList(7, 14, 21);

var_dump($sevenList('foo', 'bar', 'baz'));

// Array
// (
//    [0] => 7
//    [1] => 14
//    [2] => 21
//    [3] => foo
//    [4] => bar
//    [5] => baz
// )
```

Comment: Not really. I imagine if anyone is using this kind of pattern, it'd be http://lithify.me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php) are what you are looking for?

Example:

```
<?php
    $greet = function($name)
    {
        printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
    };

    $greet('World');
    $greet('PHP');
?>
```

Comment: yes, it is, especialy with keywork "use"  $someVar = 1; $greet = function ($name) user (&$greet) { ...

Answer (score 1):

The [functional-php](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php) library has a class for [currying (from the Docs)](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php/blob/master/docs/functional-php.md#currying):

> Since PHP allows for optional parameters, you can decide if you want to curry them or not. The default is to not curry them.
>
> ```
> use function Functional\curry;
>
> function add($a, $b, $c = 10) {
>     return $a + $b + $c;
> }
>
> // Curry only required parameters, the default, $c will always be 10
> $curriedAdd = curry('add', true);
>
> // This time, 3 parameters will be curried.
> $curriedAddWithOptional = curry('add', false);
> ```
>
> Starting with PHP7 and the implementation of the "Uniform variable syntax", you can greatly simpliy the usage of curried functions.
>
> ```
> use function Functional\curry;
>
> function add($a, $b, $c, $d) {
>     return $a + $b + $c + $d;
> }
>
> $curriedAdd = curry('add');
> $curriedAdd(10)(5)(27)(10); // -> 52
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since php5.3 you can use the "use" keyword to pass the curried argument to the scope of the returned function:

```
$add = function ($a) {
    return function ($b) use ($a) {
        return $b + $a;
    };
};

var_dump($add(2)(3)); // int (5)
```